# Print Barcode on Receipt

Tags: android, printing

I am new to Android, been trying to print a a barcode on my receipt, after looking through my printer's manual which by the way is a Zicox thermal printer I found this:

[image]

[image]

This is my first time working with a printer on Android and this looks like complete gibberish to me.  I understand that I am supposed to send a command to my printer to print the barcode so I tried the ff:

First of all the constant:

```
public static byte[] PRINT_BARCODE = {29, 107, 73};
```

Then writing the command along with my barcode to my output stream:

```
mOutputStream.write(PrinterCommands.PRINT_BARCODE);
mOutputStream.write("12345689010".getBytes());
```

This however did not work, printer blinked a couple of times and went to sleep. "Zzzzz" on LCD display.

Comment: I am not sure what the actual value of m should be. Apparently between 65 and 73, but it should also be 0, 1, 2 or 3 to select to type of barcode. Anyway, you still have to write the number of digits `n` between `m` and your sequence. in your case `(byte) 12` since you are using the format 2.

Comment: you may want to try by simply sending  0, 1 or 2 as `m` first, using the format 1. (don't know what barcode format you are using)

Comment: TO my understanding **m** selects the barcode system.  so 73 in this case according to the table is CODE128

Comment: ok, makes sense with the rest of the table. So you just need to input the number `n` between `m` and the barcode.

Comment: n? I'm confused, can you please give me an example?

Comment: your format says `29 107 m **n** d1...dn` m is 73 for code128, n should be 12 for 12 digits in the barcode.

Comment: Ahh I see now, been able to understand how these commands work with your help, thankks! :D